# Adding and removing class click function in Angular 2 Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

I'm trying to use CSS3 animation in my template, but I'm trying to find a away to add and remove class using `(click)='function()'` like jQuery way.

Question is how can I do the function below which is a jQuery in Angular 2?

This is what I have at the moment in my `SharedService`. I believe that you can't use `Renderer` angular core component in the service. Reason this is in a service is so other components can use it.

```
openBasketView() {
 $('#basketView').removeClass('fadeOutRight');
 $('#basketView').addClass('fadeInRight');
}
closeBasketView() {
 $('#basketView').removeClass('fadeInRight');
 $('#basketView').addClass('fadeOutRight');
}
```

Rather than using something like -- I like using `function` in `(click)` event is better and readable as all logic is in a block function.

component boolean

```
public showThis: Boolean = false;
```

template view

```
<div class="basket animated" [ngClass]="{'myClass': showThis}"> </div>
<button (click)="showThis = !showThis"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the display logic is in a service injected in the component, you can call the service from the template to add the toggled class. Additionally, if you want to turn on block display after clicking the button, you can put that logic in the component or in the service (in the example below, that code is in the component).

**The component:**

```
class MyComponent {
    private displayBlock = false;
    private turnOnBlockDisplay() {
        this.displayBlock = true;
    }
    private getBlockClass() {
        return this.displayBlock ? "block" : "";
    } 
    constructor (private myService: ToggleClassService, ...) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**The service:**

```
class ToggleClassService {
    private fadeIn = false;
    public toggleClass() {
        this.fadeIn = !this.fadeIn;
    }
    public getClass() {
        return this.fadeIn ? "fadeInRight" : "fadeOutRight";
    }
}
```

**The template:**

```
<div [ngClass]="['basket', 'animated', myService.getClass(), getBlockClass()]">...</div>
<button (click)="myService.toggleClass(); turnOnBlockDisplay();">Toggle</button>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.basket {
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
.basket.fadeInRight {
    background-color: red;
}
.basket.fadeOutRight {
    background-color: blue;
}
.basket.block {
    display: block;
}
```

You can test the code in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/ConnorsFan/pen/NjGNRJ) (note: the "service" is not injected).

Comment: I think in the previous comments with Aravind, I mentioned that I want to use `function()` on `click` event to update the `div` class, rather than putting the logic in the template. Is that possible? if not then ill stick with this approach which I've already provided in my question. That's why I used `SharedService` for this.

Comment: another reason is that I will be using this in other views, by doing this its a kinda cumbersome as I will have to change the conidition/class in each views.

Comment: You can write a method in your component class or in a service to toggle `showThis`, and call it like: `(click)="myService.toggleShowThis()"`.

Comment: Mind updating your answer with your suggestion?

Comment: I updated the answer. As for the codepens, I will see if I can update a codepen later.

Comment: Thanks, btw how can you add `display: block` when you click the button? instead of using `$('div.basket').css('display', 'block')`

Comment: You could include `display: block` in one of the toggled classes. Otherwise, it can be specified with `[style.display]="displayValue"` (where `displayValue` is a property of the component) or `[style.display]="myService.displayValue"`.

Comment: I want it to append `display: block` only when you click toggle. If I added to the toggled class it will be removed when the `Boolean` is `false` but if I put in both toggled classes then the `div` element will show when the page is loaded as the `div` state is false at first.

Comment: You can include `display: block` in another class, and link that class to a different boolean field (of the component or of the service). That field would be false initially, and would be set to true in the click event handler.

Comment: I enhanced the last part of the answer (with service) and the corresponding codepen.

Comment: I updated my answer to give more details about the service usage, and I moved the event handler logic inside of methods. After publishing this update, I realize that this is similar to what Aravind suggested in his last update.

Comment: Ah that's look a lot better :) I tried a similar way earlier but not in a block `function` to append class  but just css attr and using `ngStyle` instead. Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative Way not use ts side varible use function

```
<li class="mobile-links__item" #childCatLi>
    <div class="mobile-links__item-title">
     <a routerLink="{{cat.link.link}}" class="mobile-links__item-link">{{cat.category.name}}</a>
     <button class="mobile-links__item-toggle"  type="button (click)="toggleClass(childCatLi)">
       <svg class="mobile-links__item arrow" width="12px" height="7px"><use xlink:href="./assets/images/sprite.svg#arrow-rounded-down-12x7"></use></svg>
     </button>
    </div>
</li>
```

component.ts side in toogleClass

```
toggleClass(elem:HTMLElement){
        elem.classList.toggle('mobile-links__item--open');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the below code

```
<div class="basket" [class.fadeOutRight]="showThis" [class.fadeInRight]="!showThis">
<div (click)="showThis = !showThis"></div>
```

Update 1 :

```
<div class="basket" [ngClass]="getClass()">

getClass() {
   if(this.showThis)
        return 'fadeOutRight';
   else 
       retun 'fadeInRight'
}

<div [ngClass]="{ 'c1, c2, c3' : true, 'fadeOutRight' : showThis, 'fadeInRight' : !showThis }
```

Update 2:

Have the classes in an array as

```
classes:string[] = ['basket', 'animated']
<div [ngClass]="classes></div>


 <button (click)="toggleClass()"></button>

toggleClass(){
    this.classes.splice(this.classes.length-1,1); // removes the class 
    this.show=!this.show;
    if(this.show) {
        this.classes.push('fadeOutRight')
     }else {
        this.classes.push('fadeInRight')
     }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/aYAH5okLl6fYZUVfjldm?p=preview)**

Comment: I want to use `function()` and put the logic there rather than in template.

Comment: adding `[class]=""` seems to remove the html class element, makes it `class="undefined"`

Comment: you should be using `ngClass` instead check my updated answer

Comment: Yeah I've tried that and it didn't add any class at all. your answer was my initial thought before asking the question even tried using `switch` instead.

Comment: one of the above two classes only should be included correct?

Comment: Yes, just one of the two classes `fadeInRight` is to show a `div` element and the other is to hide it. So it can't be both included.

Comment: Do u want to include some classes by default irrespective of conditions

Comment: Yeah as default there are classes such as `basket animated`. Just adding `fadeInRight and Out` when clicking a button.

Comment: can you check your div `ngClass` not sure if that's finished or something? As for the button to trigger the `ngClass` is it gonna be the same `getClass`? `<button (click)="getClass()"></button>`?

Comment: pls be specific straight to the point, class should be applied to div element on button click ?

Comment: yes the class should be applied when you click a button/whatever element which I have stated in my question :) `(click)="function()"` Your first answer was right but instead of doing that way I want to use `function` on the click event.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working, can you create a pnkr/fiddle of your answer please.

Comment: @MrNew have a look at the updated answer with a plunker